# Solving two dimensional heat equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, heat-equation

[image]

I'm trying to solve this equation,I have tried separating variable method but it doesn't work.because of the second condition. I've also tried separating the variables into two groups, for instance $u=H(x) G(y,t)$ or $ u=H(t) G(x,y)$ but it doesn't work neither.Do you know any other methods to solve this equation?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us how did separation of variables fail?

Comment: I reached the result that $u$ must be just a function of $y$ but according to the last condition it doesn't need to.

Comment: The third condition will cause separation of variables to fail if $T_0$ is not 0. If you put $v(x,y,t) = u(x,y,t)-T_0$ and $T_0$ is constant then v will satisfy the same PDE, the same first boundary condition and $v(x, 0, t) = 0$ with $v(x,y,0)=f(x,y)-T_0 = g(x,y)$. You can find a separable solution for v.

Comment: The last equation is the initial condition. The first two boundary conditions give you a family of separable solutions, each with an unknown constant indexed by an integer n. The initial condition together with fourier series let you work out what the unknown constants are. The function f(x, y) need not be of the form h(x)g(y).

Comment: Would you please solve it to the end,I think there is something wrong,maybe there should be another condition to be solved completely!

Comment: The solution is very long. Have a look in Follens book on PDEs for Science and Engineering for a similar problem.